# My airport never stops searching for networks, even when I'm already connected

Tags: macos, airport

I switched to Lion soon after it came out on my MacBook Pro.  Now when I pull down the airport menu, it indicates that it is searching for networks all the time.  It does this even after I am connected to my preferred network.  I never noticed this with Leopard nor Snow Leopard.  Is this a bug?  a feature?  Should I care?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the refrigerator light problem.  It's searching because you pulled down the Airport menu.

Comment: Winning question and answer! Brilliant :-)

Comment: Seriously... ROFLMAO

Comment: @Alrescha is right. Just for completion's sake, if your Mac was constantly searching for networks and you were not opening the AirPort menu, that would then be a sign of a weak signal and your AirPort card being unable to stay connected.

Comment: This behavior is the same on Leopard / Snow Leopard and the scanning has no real effect on the performance of anything but the CPU/GPU to make the nice spinny effect.